# How to delete inner text with vi keybinding in iterm

Tags: bash, macos, vim, terminal, iterm2

I have set the option on my zshrc file `set -o vi` and I can do general motions from vim in my terminal session but I have for example `git commit -m "somestuff"` if I press di" inside "somestuff" , it won't delete the text inner the quotes, how can I do that?

Comment: x is normally used to delete text in vi

Comment: so motions like di" are exclusive of vim but not exists in vi?

Comment: `set -o vi` is not `vi`, it's a rough emulation in `bash`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-vi-Mode.html#Readline-vi-Mode